# Updating pip after updating setuptools and also maybe distribution

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distribute

I decided to upgrade pip. `pip --version` returns `pip 1.2.1` for my python 2.7

First, it seemed reasonable upgrade steuptools, because `setuptools.__version__ = '0.6'`:

```
pip install -U setuptools
....
Downloading distribute-0.7.3.zip (145kB): 145kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package distribute

Downloading/unpacking setuptools>=0.7 (from distribute)
Downloading setuptools-5.4.1.tar.gz (782kB): 782kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package setuptools

Installing collected packages: distribute, setuptools
Found existing installation: distribute 0.6.34
Uninstalling distribute:
Successfully uninstalled distribute
Running setup.py install for distribute

Found existing installation: distribute 0.6.34
Can't uninstall 'distribute'. No files were found to uninstall.
Running setup.py install for setuptools

Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/share/python
Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /usr/local/share/python
Successfully installed distribute setuptools
Cleaning up...
```

Which doesn't make sense regarding `distribute`. Do I have it, what version is it?

But now, the following doesn't work (using either -U or --upgrade option) because there are missing distribution options:

```
pip install -U pip
Downloading pip-1.5.6.tar.gz (938kB): 938kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package pip
path/to/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'entry_points'
  warnings.warn(msg)
path/to/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'extras_require'
  warnings.warn(msg)
path/to/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
  warnings.warn(msg)
path/to/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'
  warnings.warn(msg)

usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...] ...
error: invalid command 'egg_info'
```

Is there an easy way to fix this? Do I uninstall distribution or un-upgrade (and how does that work?) Thanks!

Comment: First question: Do you by any chance have two different Python 2.7 installations on the path? This is especially common on OS X, which comes with a Python 2.7 from Apple, but many people install a second one anyway (sometimes not even realizing they already have one).

Comment: Meanwhile: back when `setuptools` was somewhat stalled in the 0.6 days, `distribute` was created as a fork that could, among other things, emulate `setuptools`. As of 0.7, the two projects merged back into one. `distribute` 0.7.3 is basically a fake package to make sure `pip install -U distribute` will remove any old versions of either project and make sure you end up with only `setuptools` 0.7 or later. If that doesn't work, it may be worth trying to uninstall `distribute`, `setuptools`, and `pip`, and then install `setuptools` and `pip` with the `get-pip.py` script.

Comment: It is a Mac OS. My $PATH is a bit repetitive, but it appears to have only one python installation? I don't remember installing two: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/itt/idl/bin:/usr/local/share/python:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin

Comment: Do you remember installing _one_? If so, you have two, because Apple already installed one for you. Try `which -a python`; if you get anything but `/usr/bin/python`, you have two.

Comment: uhoh, I think I have three: /usr/local/bin/python, /usr/bin/python, /usr/local/bin/python. Ahhh. It might be only 2, just repeated location to the second python? Is there a way to figure out which I use usually and remove the other?

Comment: OK, that's the problem you need to solve first. You can't remove the Apple one, because the OS depends on it (and the next OS X update would just reinstall it anyway, if it didn't fail), but you can remove the other one. The question is whether you need it.

Comment: Some reasons you might need a second Python: (1) You need a bug fix from 2.7.8, so Apple's 2.7.2 or 2.7.5 isn't acceptable. (2) You need a prerelease version or custom build of PyObjC. (3) You need to be able to manage your site-packages without `sudo`. (4) Can't get Apple's IDLE to work with Apple's Tcl/Tk, and need IDLE. Meanwhile, do you know where the `/usr/local/bin` one came from? An installer from python.org? Homebrew? An "extra batteries" Python distro like Enthought?

Comment: Okay. none of those reasons apply - but maybe I installed all my modules on the second python? I think all site-packages are installed here: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (which is my second installation). I'll just leave it then? if many people have this too! Right, okay, your answer says that. Thanks :D And I think it was Homebrew, which makes it easier to remove if necessary. :D

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar` means it's definitely Homebrew. That's a whole other problem—from the `/opt/local/bin` on your path, I'm assuming you're using MacPorts, and using Homebrew and MacPorts on the same machine is complicated and hard to get right. But anwyay, the good news is, Homebrew gives you a risk-free way to clean things up: `brew unlink python` will get that extra Python out of the way, automatically taking care of all the complicated stuff that's necessary, and if you later change your mind, `brew link python` will undo it.

Comment: (I really wish this site allowed people without rep to chat; comments are a terrible format for this, especially with both of us editing comments to save space while the other is replying… Oh well.) Anyway, yeah, you've probably installed a bunch of modules for the Homebrew installation, but it shouldn't be hard to reinstall them. Especially once you get `pip-1.5` working, because there will probably be binary wheels for almost everything if you're using Apple's Python.

Comment: This was a year+ ago, but I remember reading mixing the two was bad, so (I think) I've never used MacPorts. Yeah :) I'll tackle removing it this weekend :) thanksthanks

Comment: While you're at it, you might want to run `brew doctor` and see if it identifies any problems for you to fix, before running any more `brew` commands. (Also, `brew update`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a little more information, it's hard to diagnose your problem, but this solution will be safe to try, and will most likely fix your problem.

First, make sure you only have one Python 2.7 (or, if you have multiple installations, make sure all the tools you're using match up—don't use /usr/local/bin/pip to try to install packages for /usr/bin/python).

Next, uninstall `setuptools`, `distribute`, and `pip`. First try to do so with `pip` itself. If it tells you there are other packages that depend on them, stop and report back before you break anything. If it fails because of permissions, fix the permissions with `chmod` and try again. If it fails because it gets confused trying to uninstall itself, that's normal; just remove the packages from your `site-packages` manually.

Finally, reinstall `pip` using the [`get-pip.py`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) script. (Unlike earlier versions, this will automatically install `setuptools` for you if needed.)